# User defined Hash partioning in RDD with key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hello i would like to make my own hash function with the key being a column "arrival delay"

the code that i had at the moment is

```
# this is for the flights 
def import_parse_rdd(data):
    # create rdd
    rdd = sc.textFile(data)
    # remove the header 
    header = rdd.first()
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda row: row != header) #filter out header
    # split by comma 
    split_rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
    row_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda line: Row(
                                             YEAR = int(line[0]),MONTH = int(line[1]),DAY = int(line[2]),DAY_OF_WEEK = int(line[3])
                                             ,AIRLINE = line[4],FLIGHT_NUMBER = int(line[5]),
                                             TAIL_NUMBER = line[6],ORIGIN_AIRPORT = line[7],DESTINATION_AIRPORT = line[8],
        SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE = line[9],DEPARTURE_TIME = line[10],DEPARTURE_DELAY = 0 if "".__eq__(line[11]) else float(line[11]),TAXI_OUT = 0 if "".__eq__(line[12]) else float(line[12]),
        WHEELS_OFF = line[13],SCHEDULED_TIME = line[14],ELAPSED_TIME = 0 if "".__eq__(line[15]) else float(line[15]),AIR_TIME = 0 if "".__eq__(line[16]) else float(line[16]),DISTANCE = 0 if "".__eq__(line[17]) else float(line[17]),WHEELS_ON = line[18],TAXI_IN = 0 if "".__eq__(line[19]) else float(line[19]),
        SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL = line[20],ARRIVAL_TIME = line[21],ARRIVAL_DELAY = 0 if "".__eq__(line[22]) else float(line[22]),DIVERTED = line[23],CANCELLED = line[24],CANCELLATION_REASON = line[25],AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY = line[26],
        SECURITY_DELAY = line[27],AIRLINE_DELAY = line[28],LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY = line[29],WEATHER_DELAY = line[30])
                           )
    return row_rdd
```

if i take flight_rdd.take(1)

```
[Row(YEAR=2015, MONTH=6, DAY=26, DAY_OF_WEEK=5, AIRLINE='EV', FLIGHT_NUMBER=4951, TAIL_NUMBER='N707EV', ORIGIN_AIRPORT='BHM', DESTINATION_AIRPORT='LGA', SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE='630', DEPARTURE_TIME='629', DEPARTURE_DELAY=-1.0, TAXI_OUT=13.0, WHEELS_OFF='642', SCHEDULED_TIME='155', ELAPSED_TIME=141.0, AIR_TIME=113.0, DISTANCE=866.0, WHEELS_ON='935', TAXI_IN=15.0, SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL='1005', ARRIVAL_TIME='950', ARRIVAL_DELAY=-15.0, DIVERTED='0', CANCELLED='0', CANCELLATION_REASON='', AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY='', SECURITY_DELAY='', AIRLINE_DELAY='', LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY='', WEATHER_DELAY='')]
```

is the output

i would like to make a user defined hash partitioning function with the key being the ARRIVAL_DELAY column.

If i could i would also like Min and Max value in the ARRIVAL_DELAY column to be used as a key to determine the distribution of the partition.

the furthest i have gone is that

```
flight_rdd.partitionBy(number of parts, key)
```

is what i understand

```
YEAR,MONTH,DAY,DAY_OF_WEEK,AIRLINE,FLIGHT_NUMBER,TAIL_NUMBER,ORIGIN_AIRPORT,DESTINATION_AIRPORT,SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE,DEPARTURE_TIME,DEPARTURE_DELAY,TAXI_OUT,WHEELS_OFF,SCHEDULED_TIME,ELAPSED_TIME,AIR_TIME,DISTANCE,WHEELS_ON,TAXI_IN,SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL,ARRIVAL_TIME,ARRIVAL_DELAY,DIVERTED,CANCELLED,CANCELLATION_REASON,AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY,SECURITY_DELAY,AIRLINE_DELAY,LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY,WEATHER_DELAY
2015,2,6,5,OO,6271,N937SW,FAR,DEN,1712,1701,-11,15,1716,123,117,95,627,1751,7,1815,1758,-17,0,0,,,,,,
2015,1,19,1,AA,1605,N496AA,DFW,ONT,1740,1744,4,15,1759,193,198,175,1188,1854,8,1853,1902,9,0,0,,,,,,
2015,3,8,7,NK,1068,N519NK,LAS,CLE,2220,2210,-10,12,2222,238,229,208,1824,450,9,518,459,-19,0,0,,,,,,
2015,9,21,1,AA,1094,N3EDAA,DFW,BOS,1155,1155,0,12,1207,223,206,190,1562,1617,4,1638,1621,-17,0,0,,,,,,
```

this is the unprocessed version of the data set

Comment: are you reading a csv file? if so using spark.read.format("csv").load("path/to/csv") will load the data as dataframe, then you can do whatever transformations you want and at the end you can specify the column name using which you want to create partitions

Comment: if possible, add sample data from the file you are reading, to this question

Comment: i would like to do this in RDD since i have no clue how this works

Comment: anyone know how this could be done?